# Unity/C# bounding box of object from image

Tags: c#, image-processing, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

**Goal:** I would like to find out the width of an real-life object seen through the AR camera of Vuforia(webcam/phone camera).

---

**Idea:** use the AR camera from Vuforia to take a photo, and find the bounding box of an object(for example a mug) from that image; then get the width of the bounding box(with the width information I will scale a 3d object).

example:

[image example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x1Qd.png)

[image example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEt3D.jpg)

I'm aware that there is OpenCV for unity in the asset store but i'm looking for a free method.
If you have any ideas of how to achieve the proposed idea or any new ideas of how to implement the goal, anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible only if the phone can first recognize some sort of a marker (could be a piece of paper). That would map the 3d environment to the real world environment. Otherwise you would have to guess the actual size (lets say in centimeters) of the object. You can never tell the size, because you do not know if the image is taken 10 cm. from the object or 1 m. from the object.

Answer (score 0):

(EDITED)

After some search, I found this excelent method [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/49943/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-on-screen-render-size.html) for you:

```
public static Rect ObjectBounds(GameObject go)
    {
        Vector3 cen = go.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;
        Vector3 ext = go.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents;
        Vector2[] extentPoints = new Vector2[8]
        {
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x-ext.x, cen.y-ext.y, cen.z-ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x+ext.x, cen.y-ext.y, cen.z-ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x-ext.x, cen.y-ext.y, cen.z+ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x+ext.x, cen.y-ext.y, cen.z+ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x-ext.x, cen.y+ext.y, cen.z-ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x+ext.x, cen.y+ext.y, cen.z-ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x-ext.x, cen.y+ext.y, cen.z+ext.z)),
         HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(new Vector3(cen.x+ext.x, cen.y+ext.y, cen.z+ext.z))
        };
        Vector2 min = extentPoints[0];
        Vector2 max = extentPoints[0];
        foreach (Vector2 v in extentPoints)
        {
            min = Vector2.Min(min, v);
            max = Vector2.Max(max, v);
        }
        return new Rect(min.x, min.y, max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
    }
```

An example of calling the method to a rect and drawing it on screen:

```
void OnGUI () //EditorGUI.DrawRect must be in this function name
{
    //create a rect using the method and the GameObject this script is attached to (gameObject)
    Rect boundsRect = new Rect(GUIRectWithObject(gameObject));
    //draw a blue rect on the box of the rect (will hide the object)
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(boundsRect, Color.blue);
}
```

For you to get the width of the rect write:

```
float boundswidth = boundsRect.width;
```

Comment: i'm sorry maybe i haven't been clear enough, the object is a real 3d object seen through the webcam/phone camera...i updated the question

Comment: @Nap now I understand... The example I provided is for getting the size of the actual 3d object that exist in the scene relative to its rotation, but what you are trying to achive is different, ill check for it.

Comment: @Nap I edited my answer to what you need, this script will create a rect of the "seen" box of your gameObject